# How do I debug a python/pyglet memory leak?

Tags: python, debugging, pyglet

I'm running my game code on pyglet 1.1.4, and am seeing what looks to me like a memory leak. That is, while the code is executing the RSS continually increases until eventually my laptop starts swapping and eventually the code exits with a bus error.

I investigated with guppy: I did a heap dump once at startup, once after the first slowdown due to running out of memory and hitting swap, then once this is detected I exited pyglet and did one last heap dump. I noticed that all three dumps showed approximately the same heap size (approximately 18 MB), even though htop shows the code is using gigabytes of memory.

From what I've read, these heap dumps only show python memory usage, which means the rest of the memory would be occupied by C code. If my understanding is correct, this would seem to indicate a memory leak in the ctypes that pyglet is generating. My understanding of the underlying code is hazy, so please feel free to correct any incorrect terminology I may be using or any other errors in my understanding/description.

Here was the Apple crash report when I encountered the bus error:
https://gist.github.com/1612500

Here is the code that contains the memory problem:
https://github.com/greenmoss/NotOrion/tarball/bus_error

I created a utility to automatically trigger the condition. To run it, download/untar the above tarball, then cd to the "demo" directory, then execute "./label_move.py". If you allow this utility to run continually, it should replicate the behavior described above. If you have a lot of free memory, it may take a while to use it all before it hits swap.

So to debug/fix this, it sounds like I will need to delve into the underlying pyglet (or even C) code. It was pointed out to me in another gamedev [question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/21128/how-to-debug-pyglet-opengl-bus-errors) that I should use gdb. I don't really know C or gdb, and adding the complexity of python + pyglet is overwhelming me.

So, can someone give me an example of a gdb debugging session using my code above?